# Angular Js+Asp.net Web api session management

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application, javascript-framework

I'm new to both angular and web api, I've worked previously on asp.net web forms and java jsp's my question is since angular is pure js framework and web api is used for Http services ,if we build web applications using both these technologies how can session management be handled, can we create session in web api controllers ? If we can, since webapi (REST) is stateless does it violate the principle of REST statelessness , please clarify

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular and WebAPI do not change how to track session in web applications.  Usually, this is done with a cookie that is sent with every request.  Since cookies follow domains, Angular requests will always send in the cookie (just like they did before).

To answer each of your questions:

> can we create session in web api controllers?

Yes, we can access session through `HttpContext.Current.Session`.

> does it violate the principle of REST statelessness?

REST (Representational State Transfer) doesn't have a principle of statelessness.  HTTP is a stateless protocol.  REST says that calls to the server (using HTTP verbs etc.) should progress state of the application.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation to comment in response to him yet, but David Tyron seems to be misunderstanding the term "stateless" in this context. Obviously, both the API and the UI using it have to maintain and progress data that can be properly labeled a state, but in the context of RESTful APIs, "stateless" is usually specifically referring to the fact that the API doesn't keep track of the **client's** state.

The idea behind this is that each request to the API must include all of the necessary UI information to perform the required action. In other words, each call must happen in isolation and independent from each other.

Sessions absolutely violate this principle, though it's probably the most common thing that is used that prevents something from being 100% RESTful.

(On a related note, Cookies still count as stateless since the client is the one responsible for storing that data.)